# Joda-Time Period Calculation

Tags: java, date, wolfram-mathematica, jodatime

I'm having strange behavior from Joda-Time's period calculation for getting someone's age. If someone is born on January 5, 1970 then as of today they should be 46 years old and 1 day. However, if I use the following age calculation:

```
LocalDate birthdate = new LocalDate(1970,1,5);
LocalDate today = new LocalDate();
Period period = new Period(birthdate, today, PeriodType.yearMonthDay());
int age = period.getYears();
```

And joda-time says period is `P45Y1D`. I've tried this on [wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=born%20january%205%2C%201970) to verify I'm not crazy and it agrees with me. What is joda-time doing here that's giving it a different result?

Comment: What is the clock set to on your system? I just ran your code on my machine and it printed `P46Y1D`

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but is your computer's clock set correctly? :) (It might be worth checking with `LocalDate today = new LocalDate(2016, 1, 6);`)

Comment: Maybe try to set 'today' manually (new LocalDate(2016, 1, 6)) to narrow down the problem

Comment: Yep, somehow the clock was messed up. I'm still stuck in 2015 so I just didn't even notice that that was the date year it was using for the calculation.

Comment: @AndyTurner or Richard… Please post an Answer based on your comments so it can be accepted and considered closed. Or retract the Question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is because your computer's clock is set incorrectly. Hardcoding the date as follows produces the expected result:

```
LocalDate birthdate = new LocalDate(1970,1,5);
LocalDate today = new LocalDate(2016, 1, 6);  // Rather than relying on system clock. 
Period period = new Period(birthdate, today, PeriodType.yearMonthDay());
int age = period.getYears();  // 46.
```